# Java String.format()

Tags: java, string, formatting

I have a string and I want to format it in a custom way.
This is my String:

```
String amount = "355128000";
```

I want it to be formatted like this way:

```
String formattedAMount = "3 551 280,00"
```

With a space after first number and a group of 3 numbers and a comma at the end before two nubmers

Comment: Read the [javadoc of `NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). It can do this. `String.format` cannot.

Comment: @Jorn I used "%,d" but didn't get what i want the result was : 355 128 000 that's not what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of `NumberFormatter` and specify options:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NumberFormatExample {

    private static final DecimalFormat numberFormatter;

    static {
        numberFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

        // Configure/override
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = numberFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\u00a0'); // non-breaking space
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        numberFormatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        numberFormatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }

    public static String formatNumber(String rawNumber) {
        return numberFormatter.format(Long.parseLong(rawNumber) / 100d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String amount = "355128000";
        System.out.println(formatNumber(amount)); // 3 551 280,00
    }
}
```

### Edit

It looks like you can use the French formatter, and specify just the min fraction digits.

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NumberFormatExample {

    private static final DecimalFormat numberFormatter;

    static {
        numberFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);

        // Configure
        numberFormatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }

    public static String formatNumber(String rawNumber) {
        return numberFormatter.format(Long.parseLong(rawNumber) / 100d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String amount = "355128000";
        System.out.println(formatNumber(amount)); // 3 551 280,00
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but your result is "355 128 000,00" what i'm trying to achieve that one "3 551 280,00" the double will add extra zeros at the end

Comment: @BAKHALEDIbrahim then you need to divide by 100

Comment: Thank you so much the trick was dividing by 100 Appreciate your help thanks.

Comment: @BAKHALEDIbrahim yeah, the number formatter formats an integer/floating-point number only. It does not know, nor can it pre-determine if it needs to divide for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it with `String.format()` if you first convert it to `double':

```
String amount = "355128000";
double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(amount);

String formattedAmount = String.format("%,.2f", amountDouble);
// 355,128,000.00
```

if you want to look it exactly like as you showed you can achieve this by:

```
String formattedAmount = String.format("%,.2f", amountDouble).replace(",", " ").replace(".", ",");
```

But `String.format()` might not be the best way for this purpose, use [DecimalFormat](https://www.baeldung.com/java-decimalformat) instead.

Comment: Hey erkebel I tried that but it adds extra zeros at the end due to converting to double what I really want to achieve is that format "3 551 280,00" as you can see the last two zeros are presented in the original number

Comment: This can be achieved by dividing the amountDouble by 100:
`double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(amount) / 100;`

Comment: Yes that's what I did thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I would forgo `NumberFormat` and just do it as follows using the `France locale` which matches your desired format.

```
String amount = "355128000";

UnaryOperator<String> format = str -> {
    long v = Long.parseLong(str);
    return String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%,.2f", v / 100.);
};


System.out.println(format.apply(amount));
```

prints

```
3 551 280,00
```